# No se pueden usar contains en un HashSet después de agregarlo

Tags: java

Intenté saber si podemos agregar algo a una lista/collections con los `HashSet` y averiguar si está ahí.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stupid {
    private final int i ;
    public Stupid(int i) {
        this.i = i ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stupid[] a = new Stupid[2] ;
        a[0] = new Stupid(2) ;
        a[1] = new Stupid(1) ;
        Arrays.sort(a);

        HashSet<Stupid> hs = new HashSet<>() ;
        hs.add(new Stupid(1)) ;
        System.out.println(hs.contains(new Stupid(1))) ;
    }
}
```

Obtengo:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>javac Stupid.java

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java Stupid
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Stupid cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (Stupid is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
        at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1249)
        at Stupid.main(Stupid.java:14)
```

¿De dónde viene el `sort`?

¿Por qué el cast de Stupid en Comparable no es posible?

¿Por qué no se pueden usar `contains` en un `HashSet` después de agregarlo?

Comment: El stacktrace indica que no falla en el *contains*....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿De dónde viene el sort?

Viene de aquí:

```
   Arrays.sort(a);
```

¿Por qué el cast de Stupid en Comparable no es posible?

Porque Stupid necesita implementar Comparable según lo que dice el método java.util.Arrays.sort(Object o). Lo puedes implematar así:

```
public class Stupid implements Comparable<Stupid> {

///aquí vamos a implementar java.lang.Comparable
///y lo hacemos con el campo i. Supongo que eso querrías.
@Override
public int compareTo(Stupid otro) {
    return i.compareTo(otro.i);
}
```

Quizás también requiera implementar equals y por ende hashCode porque 
veo que los quieres usar en hashSets.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otro) {
    return (otro instanceof Stupid 
            && i == ((Stupid)otro).i);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() { return i; }
```

Estos overrides de equals y hashCode serían si quisieras que fueran iguales solo sí su propiedad "i" fuera la misma.

¿Por qué no se pueden usar contains en un HashSet después de agregarlo?

```
 Si Stupid implementa Comparable debe de poderse usar.
```